# How to use lockstat.txt on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, lock

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my machine. I want to use lockstat. I have looked at `Documentation/lockstat.txt` but I am not getting how to use it, if possible please help me out.

I am working on a project adapting system software like the Linux kernel. I read one paper titled *"Experience on Comparison of Operating Systems Scalability on the Multi-core Architecture"* that tells how to detect bottlenecks using bench-marking. I am following their experimental approach and am able to generate a profiling report using the profile tool, but I am not able to detect bottlenecks from this profiling report.

Basically, I am not able to explore the `no-vmlinux` part, and I am not able to find `no-vmlinux` functions related to bottlenecks. Also I am not able to use *lockstat.txt* as there is no file in `/proc/sys/kernel/lock_stat`.

Answer (score 2):

Lockstat is an optional kernel feature. It is mostly useful for people who are debugging kernel drivers. It is not included in Ubuntu's default kernel. You need to recompile the kernel with the `CONFIG_LOCK_STAT` option.